# Writing Java code to check how many instances of an AWS function are running

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I want to write some Java code to see how many instances of a specific AWS Lambda function are currently running, but I can't find an appropriate API to do this.

I've searched the web (AWS Documentation, StackOverflow, and general Google searches) but the only information I can find describes how to use the AWS Web Interface to view graphs. This is not what I need.

Does such an API exist? I imagine that the AWS dashboard uses some API to get its statistics, but maybe this is isn't publicly available?

Comment: BTW - is somebody votes to close this question, could they *please* say why. At the very least it will allow me to write better questions in future.

Comment: One way would be for your AWS lambda function to increment a global counter when it starts and decrement the global counter when it completes.  You can read the global counter whenever you want to know how many AWS lambda functions are running.

Comment: IDK if you can see these for yourself , but the votes are for "needing focus" and "not suitable for site - seeking recommendation for books, etc." IMO your question is fine, as you're asking for *any* API to do this, not the best API for general use.

Comment: Thanks Edward, I've never clicked on the "close" link before - I'd always assumed it would close my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get this information via [Cloudwatch metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html) [image].

Just a small catch that this information has a lag of 60 seconds. To get the number of concurrent connections at any instant, there is no direct way.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but is there a way to do this in code?

Comment: @Stormcloud like each AWS service, you can use it through main AWS SDKs. For instance here is an example retrieving a CloudWatch metric from Java SDK https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-cloudwatch-get-metrics.html.

Comment: Thank you Jordi - I've been looking in completely the wrong place. I was expecting an API in the AWS Lambda Client.